# How to smooth out 2D rotation in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D game in Unity and one feature I'm trying to implement is flipping the player if the mouse position is over 90 meaning he is always facing the direction of the mouse.

```
        Vector3 mousePosition = UtilsClass.GetMouseWorldPosition();
        Vector3 aimDirection = (mousePosition - transform.position).normalized;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(aimDirection.y, aimDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        Vector3 aimLocalScale = Vector3.one;
        if (angle > 90 || angle < -90)
        {
            rotate = true;
        } 
        else
        {
            rotate = false;
        }
        gameObject.transform.localScale = aimLocalScale;

        if (rotate == true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, 0f);
        }
```

However, one problem I am having is that one, it's very finicky and if you go too fast the player is looking in the wrong direction, and two, if you look straight up, he doesn't know exactly where to look and keeps snapping left and right really fast.

Does anyone know a way to fix this allowing for a smoother more functional flipping?

Answer (score 0):

Try flipping the sprite by adjusting its scale from 1 to -1. Then implement that into a FlipSprite() method and just call it when you want to flip it

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit. Because I'm trying to implement this but it flips on the wrong axis.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to flip and sprite one approach could be to inverse the localScale of the sprite, like this:

```
private void FlipSprite()
{
    // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
    Vector3 flippedScale = transform.localScale;
    flippedScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = flippedScale;
}
```

I suggest you to keep a boolean variable like `isFacingRight` to keep tracking the direction the sprite is looking at!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you use the same rotate threshold for when the character is facing right and left, so when you straddle the threshold he flips a lot and its bad UX for the player.

Solution : make the rotate threshold dynamic so each time the player rotates the threshold gets pushed down.

```
float thresholdAngle = 90.0f;
```

change angle > 90 || angle < -90 to

```
if (angle > thresholdAngle || angle < -1.0f * thresholdAngle)
```

Then add in

```
    if (rotate == true)
    {
        transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
        thresholdAngle = 110.0f;
    }
    else
    {
        transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, 0f);
        thresholdAngle = 80.0f;
    }
```

I'm not sure which way your character faces first so you may have to swap the thresholdAngle = 110.0f with the threshold = 80.0f;